# Como funciona um Dependency Injection Framework? Eles são úteis em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arquitetura-de-software, design-pattern, injeção-de-dependência

O pessoal do Java e C# vive citando *frameworks* de Injeção de Dependências.

Conheço o padrão de projetos da Injeção de Dependência, mas nunca trabalhei com tais *frameworks*. Na verdade, não faço a menor ideia de como funcionam. Alguém poderia me explicar?

A turma do Ruby costuma dizer que, no Ruby, tais *frameworks* são desnecessários, pois a própria linguagens oferece facilidades para gerenciar isso.

```
class A
  def foo
    'foo'
  end
end

class B
  def initialize(dependencia = A)
    @dependencia = dependencia.new
  end

  def metodo
    puts @dependencia.foo
  end
end

B.new.metodo # 'foo'

class Mock
  def foo
    'foobar'
  end
end

B.new(Mock).metodo # 'foobar'
```

<sub>Obs.: No exemplo acima eu passo a *classe* como parâmetro, mas é claro que poderia passar simplesmente a instância.</sub>

A classe B acima, por exemplo, usa a classe A como dependência *default*, mas permite que um *mock* seja injetado opcionalmente, para testes unitários.

É recomendado usar esta abordagem?

Comment: Encontrei um tópico bem interessante sobre abordagens diferentes para implementar injeção de dependência em Ruby no link abaixo. É a segunda parte de 3 posts abordando dicas de Design Orientado a Objetos com Ruby. Vale a pena conferir. - http://shipit.resultadosdigitais.com.br/blog/dicas-de-design-orientado-a-objetos-com-ruby-parte-2/ Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

Nenhuma linguagem *precisa* de um framework para Injeção de Dependência (DI - *Dependency Injection*). Um framework só é interessante quando ele economiza seu trabalho.

## Ninguém *precisa* de um framework

Segundo o conceito de DI apresentado na pergunta, é verdade que "no Ruby, tais frameworks são desnecessários", mas também em qualquer outra linguagem.

Como veremos a seguir existem várias técnicas simples e diretas que permitem fazer Injeção de Dependências ou algum tipo de Inversão de Controle (IoC - *Inversion of Control*) sem necessidade de framework em qualquer linguagem Orientada a Objetos.

## Técnicas de DI sem frameworks

Fazer Injeção de Dependência sem frameworks é relativamente simples.

### Construtor

Como no exemplo apresentado na pergunta, o objeto simplesmente recebe o tipo ou instância da qual ele depende em seu construtor. Esta é uma das formas mais simples de se fazer isso sem a necessidade de um framework, sendo facilmente implementado em qualquer linguagem.

### Método *Setter*

Uma alternativa seria ter um método *setter* para receber as dependências, o que é ruim no sentido de ser menos intuitivo ao desenvolvedor, porém permitiria atender ao caso de uma referência circular.

### Atributo de Classe

Outra possibilidade, o que é geralmente implementado por framerworks, é injetar a dependência diretamente nos atributos de uma classe, mesmo que sejam privados. Isso é feito utilizando algum tipo de reflexão nos objetos gerenciados pelo framework.

## O que se entende por Injeção de Dependência

Particularmente, eu classificaria o exemplo da pergunta como algum tipo específico de Inversão de Controle, mas não puramente uma Injeção de Dependência. No máximo, creio que o exemplo fica num certo limiar entre ser e não ser.

Diferente de como funciona a [definição oficial de DI](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), o código do exemplo não provê à classe `B` um componente pronto para uso, mas sim um tipo.

Embora você tenha tirado de `A` a responsabilidade de *descobrir* qual é a implementação correta, **`A` continua responsável por criar sua própria dependência**.

**E se `B` tivesse uma dependência `C`? E se `C` tivesse uma dependência `D`?**

Enfim, o exemplo não satisfaz alguns requisitos que deram origem ao conceito de DI, tal como o caso de uma hierarquia de dependências completa.

### Inversão de Controle vs. Injeção de Dependência

DI é um tipo de IoC, relacionado a dependências.

Porém, Inversão de Controle é uma forma mais abstrata de tirar uma responsabilidade de certas classes e deixá-la a cargo de outras mais especializadas.

Por exemplo, qualquer framework com controladores (*controllers*) onde o nome dos métodos correspondem às URLs que atendem ou que são mapeados usando rotas. Esses frameworks geralmente implementam o padrão *Front Controller*, que é um controlador "mestre" que lê os parâmetros HTTP e direciona a requisição para o devido controlador.

Outro exemplo são entidades mapeadas para o banco de dados. Você simplesmente define os atributos e certas propriedades e alguma outra classe de um framework fica responsável por ler e gravar de uma tabela.

Note que você faz Inversão de Controle sempre que você implementa uma classe "passiva", isto é, ela não é executada diretamente, mas através de um gerenciador ou indiretamente.

## DI é mais do que simplesmente passar objetos

Por outro lado, um IoC Container, ou framework de Inversão de Controle, como o Spring no Java, é responsável por mais do que simplesmente instanciar objetos e passar por parâmetro.

### Notação declarativa

Usar anotações como `@Inject` ou `@Autowired` é uma forma declarativa de definir as dependências e delegar a injeção nos métodos, atributos ou construtores.

Você não precisa fazer a ligação dos componentes manualmente, nem ter código de instanciação dentro das suas classes. O framework implementa o *assembler*, que irá criar e ligar seus componentes.

Menos código para manter, menos manutenção e menos dor de cabeça.

### Gerenciar o grafo de objetos

A maioria dos casos reais de dependências não são tão simples como o exemplo.

Como já foi citado, deixar que `A` seja responsável por criar ou até mesmo gerenciar as dependênicas de `B` seria uma clara violação do princípio de DI.

Um framework de DI vai instanciar todos os seus objetos e colocá-los num contexto especial, determinar as suas dependências que estão devidamente declaradas e tentar preencher as ligações necessárias. Ele vai avisar se houver problemas ao criar um dos objetos ou se faltar alguma ligação.

### Inversão de Controle da Configuração

O problema de fazer DI com código é que você continua acoplando as dependências de forma *hard-coded*.

Existem muitos componentes que podem ser reusados em diferentes contextos com algum parâmetro com configuração diferentes. Por exemplo, um componente que monitora diretórios e copia arquivos poderia ser instanciado várias vezes apontando para diferentes diretórios e então poderia ser ligado a diferentes componentes de importação de arquivo.

A configuração das dependências via XML ou outro arquivo externo aumenta o reuso e permite diferentes configurações da aplicação sem modificar o código.

Embora ninguém goste muito de XML hoje em dia, eu tampouco gosto de código com `ifs` para verificar se você está num ambiente de teste ou de produção ou uma grande quantidade de meta informação "sujando" minhas classes.

### Escopos

Nem sempre é desejável criar uma nova instância das dependências a cada injeção realizada. Nem sempre é desejável injetar a mesma instâncias em todos os lugares.

O escopo de cada componente pode variar.

Imagine o caso de você querer injetar um *data source* para conexão com o banco de dados que depende do usuário atualmente logado no sistema. Seria um escopo de sessão.

Ou então você quer injetar as configurações do sistema em todas as suas classes. Temos um escopo global (*singleton*).

Claro que você pode fazer isso sem um framework, mas no seu exemplo você teria que refatorar o código se decidisse mudar de um escopo para outro, enquanto com um framework bastaria alterar uma simples configuração.

## [Porque eu odeio frameworks](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.219431.12&)

Consigo entender bem o motivo que leva muitas pessoas a terem aversão a frameworks ou qualquer coisa que seja muito "pesada".

Veja, há duas abordagens principais que podemos usar quando a arquitetura de uma aplicação vai ser definida:

### Arquitetura completa

Podemos começar com uma arquitetura **completa**, como um servidor de aplicação Java EE, e então selecionar os components que forem necessários.

Esta opção é a considerada mais "segura" por muitos desenvolvedores. Mesmo você levando um "caminhão" de coisas desnecessárias, o dia em que você precisar de algo, vai estar ali.

Porém, as coisas não são as mil maravilhas. O desenvolvimento é mais lento e é mais difícil depurar o sistema num ambiente mais complexo.

### Arquitetura minimalista

Podemos ainda começar com uma arquitetura **minimalista**, adicionando então somente aquilo que precisarmos.

Esta é a opção mais flexível, porém exige conhecimento mais profundo sobre a plataforma, tecnologias e sobre como criar uma implementação de qualidade, caso contrário você acaba com um emaranhado de gambiarras.

### O que isso tem a ver com DI?

Na primeira abordagem, o desenvolvedor já pode usar desde o início um framework de DI, sem pensar se ele realmente precisa disso. Na outra abordagem, ele terá que pensar se vai precisar e então adicionar em sua arquitetura.

Ambas as abordagens podem redundar num produto bom ou ruim, dependendo de vários fatores, mas principalmente da experiência e conhecimento da equipe.

Pessoalmente eu prefiro a segunda opção, principalmente se trabalhar sozinho. Porém, se nem todos os seus colegas tem a mesma facilidade de mudar rapidamente o código, refatorar e recomeçar partes da aplicação do zero, então a primeira abordagem fica mais atrativa. Afinal, quando você tem centenas ou milhares de pessoas trabalhando na sua empresa, é mais fácil ensinar como usar um framework do que todos os conceitos de um bom design para que elas possam fazer isso por si mesmas.

## Considerações

Nenhuma linguagem precisa de um framework de DI, porém saber usá-los corretamente pode livrar o desenvolvedor de escrever e manter boa quantidade de código, além de evitar que ele reinvente certas rodas.

Muitos problemas com frameworks de DI são relacionados a:

1. Não entender como o framework funciona
2. Não realizar devidamente a configuração do framework
3. Ter um modelo de objetos ruim (muito acoplado) ou complexo em si mesmo
4. Não saber depurar devidamente os problemas (logs, mensagens de erro)

Além disso, há todos os tipos de sabores de framerworks de DI: simples, complexos, pequenos e grandes.

Eu sei que não é fácil. Para quem está começando é difícil entender o que o framework faz. É difícil entender padrões de projeto. É difícil simplesmente dividir a implementação em classes e métodos.

Eu já fui e voltei nessa questão de usar ou não frameworks, seja para DI ou alguma outra aplicação. Algumas vezes deixei de usar frameworks porque não entendia como eles funcionavam. Então fui melhorando meu código e cheguei à conclusão de que tinha feito o mesmo que o framework já fazia. Aí fica mais fácil optar por utilizá-los ou não.

Comment: Ótima resposta, só (1) Não ficou claro para mim a diferença entre IoC e DI, (2) Por que meu exemplo não é DI? Se eu passasse a *instância* da dependência por parâmetro ao invés da classe em si, seria DI? --- Gostei do link sobre *frameworks*, já tá nos favoritos. Muitas vezes fico em dúvida entre usar Singleton (ruim para testabilidade) ou usar DI mas ter que justamente lidar com o "trabalho sujo" de injetar todas aquelas dependências manualmente.

Comment: Esta figura ilustra bem o drama =) http://i.imgur.com/boKew3s.png

Comment: @RubyGuy Atualizei a resposta. Ela já ficou bem grande e complexa, mas tentei reorganizar. Espero que agora esteja mais claro.

Comment: Desculpe @utluiz por abusar da sua paciência =) Ficou bem clara sua resposta, tenha certeza de que ela ajudou.

Comment: @RubyGuy Eu reconheço que antes não estava muito bem explicado. Na verdade foi bom ter reescrito a resposta, pelo menos acho que está minimamente inteligível. :)