# Como refatorar um programa por Injeção de Dependência

Tags: java, design-pattern

Alguém poderia me explicar o que é o padrão de Injeção de Dependências e como refatorar o seguinte código?

```
public class Motor{
   ICombustivel combustível;

   public Motor(){
     combustível = new Gasolina();
   }
}
```

Comment: Relacionada:[O que é injeção de dependência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20770/o-que-%C3%A9-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia?rq=1)

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101.E http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40806/101. Com essas acho que a pergunta talvez seja duplicata.